# Use only local library with cross compiler

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, arm, libtool

I'm trying to build one application with cross compiler on linux. Application is based on OpenEmbedded project. Compiler and all cross compiled libraries are located in build folder. But for one package build script is trying to use a library from my linux environment.

Command which is called from make script at the end:

> /bin/sh ./arm-ABC-linux-gnueabi-libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link
> arm-ABC-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8
> -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp  -g --std=c++0x -pthread  -L/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/opt/my/lib
> -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/opt/my/lib
> -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -L/opt/my/lib -o modbus_server_test modbus_server_test.o Serial.o SerialUtil.o Crc.o RtuFramer.o Pdu.o
> SerialMaster.o
> /home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-2.la
> -lcrypt -luuid -lrt -lcrypt  -lpthread -ldl **-lexpat** -lstdc++

Most important from here that is use -lexpat flag for libexpat.so.1.5.2 library. This library is cross compiled and located in the build folder, and at the same time, we have one in my linux environment.

As result I recieve the next error:

> | arm-ABC-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link:
> arm-ABC-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8
> -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -g --std=c++0x -pthread -Wl,-rpath-link -Wl,/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/opt/my/lib
> -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -o .libs/modbus_server_test modbus_server_test.o Serial.o SerialUtil.o Crc.o RtuFramer.o Pdu.o
> SerialMaster.o
> -L/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/opt/my/lib
> -L/opt/my/lib /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-2.so -L/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
> **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so**
> /home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libuuid.so
> -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl **/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libexpat.so**
> /home/ABC/build/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libstdc++.so
> -lm -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/apr/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/ABC/build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
>
> | **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so**: file not recognized: File
> format not recognized
>
> | collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> | make[2]: *** [modbus_server_test] Error 1

From output I can see that it include two libraries: one from linux environment (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so which is x86) and one from the build folder (build/sysroots/armv7a-ABC-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libexpat.so which is for ARM).At the end it complains about x86 type.

How can I exclude this library from searching in global environment? Why it even trying to use both of them?

Comment: Can you try compiling and linking a simple program (with `arm-ABC-linux-gnueabi-gcc`) that uses only libexpat? Would throw more light on the problem.